# How can I keep using my main application as an active form after Process.Start?

Tags: c#

I want to open it in Photoshop when the picture is clicked next to it in my application. I used the following code for this:

```
// var arg = "\"" + CurretFolder + "\\" + CurrentPicture + "\"";
var arg = "\"D:\\pictures\\test_01.jpg\"";
Process.Start("photoshop.exe", arg);
```

However, when the image is opened in PhotoShop, I want to keep using my application in the foreground as an active form and I want to continue working with shortcuts etc. I tried something like this:

```
var prg = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProcessName.Contains("MyProgram"));
// var arg = "\"" + CurretFolder + "\\" + CurrentPicture + "\"";
var arg = "\"D:\\pictures\\test_01.jpg\"";
Process.Start("photoshop.exe", arg);

TopMost = true;
prg?.Refresh();
// 
Activate();
Focus();
Select();
```

But it did not happen. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe one solution is to start PhotoShop as minimized window. Then your main app will stay on foreground.

Comment: Try Process.Start with a ProcessStartInfo instance and set its WindowStyle; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle?view=net-8.0. Also note that Process.Start doesn't wait for the process to actually load, create its main window and steal the focus. Maybe WaitForInputIdle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforinputidle?view=net-8.0 and then give it few more CPU ticks before you try to get the focus back. relevant read: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253

Comment: @rene The problem is that it is not known how long PhotoShop will load. It may load slowly and force its topmost position at the end. Anyway WaitForInputIdle may help.

Comment: seems rather user un-friendly, since the user clicks open the image this action should have higher priority and it should be the active window

Comment: consider reading tag descriptions to not use totally irrelevant ones `active-form` is `ActiveForm is a widget that builds an interactive HTML form for one or multiple data models.`

Answer (score 1):

`Process.Start` is going to return well before the application window for that process is displayed, so anything you do immediately after that call will be overridden by what happens later. The first thing to try is to call `WaitForInputIdle` on your `Process` object. That will block until the application reports to Windows that it is ready to receive input, which will be after the application window has been displayed. This will not work for all applications but I suspect that it will for Photoshop.

```cs
Process.Start("photoshop.exe", arg).WaitForInputIdle();

Activate();
```

Note that `Activate` is the one and only method you call to activate a form. I understand that you were probably throwing mud at the wall but, if `Activate` doesn't work, nothing else will. That especially goes for `TopMost`, which has nothing at all to do with focus.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to force your form to be activated, so call `Activate` in a `Deactivate` event handler:

```
private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => Activate();
```

Of course, besides Photoshop, other windows will also be affected. You can use the Windows APIs [`GetForegroundWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow) and [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) to filter activated windows.

```
private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), out int processId);
    var p = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
    if(p != null && p.MainModule.FileName.EndsWith("photoshop.exe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        Activate();
}
```

BTW, I don't know why `Activate` doesn't always succeed in testing, but it seems to work better when combined with `TopMost = true`